# jquery event on checkbox changed, I can't remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox which, when it's checked, I want to show the input for the company name and set this input required.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label>Company Profile</label>
    <input id="CompanyProfile" name="CompanyProfile" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="YES" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" value="1">
</div>
<div id="divCompanyName" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hide">
   <label>Company Name<span>*</span></label>
   <input name="CompanyName" id="CompanyName" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" type="text">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery("#CompanyProfile").change(function(){    
    if(this.checked){
        jQuery("#divCompanyName").removeClass='hide';
        jQuery("#CompanyName").prop('required', true);
    }
    else{
        jQuery("#divCompanyName").addClass='hide';
        jQuery("#CompanyName").prop('required', false);
    }
});
```

The "required" attribute works. When I check the checkbox, I can see in the debugger that the "required" is added to the input. But the "hide" class is not removed.

I've done a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sincos/zu84w61j/

This's probably something simple, but I can't find it. Can you help please?

Comment: `.addClass='hide'` should be `.addClass('hide')`. Same for removeClass

Comment: Yes! I knew that this was a simple error that I couldn't find it! I use it elsewhere in my code and I've compared it and I've never seen the difference between lines... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, with jQuery, these attributes need to be in parentheses and quotes, like so:

```
jQuery(".class_name").removeClass("class_name");
```

And if you're trying to addClass or removeClass to an ID:

```
jQuery("#ID_name").removeClass("class_name");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use as .addClass("hide") and .removeClass("hide")

```
https://api.jquery.com/addclass/
https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/
```

```js
jQuery("#CompanyProfile").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    jQuery("#divCompanyName").removeClass('hide');
    jQuery("#CompanyName").prop('required', true);
  } else {
    jQuery("#divCompanyName").addClass('hide');
    jQuery("#CompanyName").prop('required', false);
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <label>Company Profile</label>
  <input id="CompanyProfile" name="CompanyProfile" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="YES" data-off="NO" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" value="1">
</div>

<div id="divCompanyName" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hide">
  <label>Company Name<span>*</span>
  </label>
  <input name="CompanyName" id="CompanyName" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: When I saw your code, I couldn't find the difference between yours and mine... I couldn't see that I had used an equal rather then the parenthesis... thx